# Allow optional space

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I'm writing a book in a language that has lengthy words yet poor support/scope for hyphenation. My current book is far from justified. I would like to manually mark places within words where LaTeX could introduce a space if necessary (break a single long word into two words) instead of optional hyphens.

I believe `\allowbreak` should work but I can't get it to work in normal body text. Is there an alternative to allowbreak? Should I enclose my entire book text within a `\texttt` (which I think is necessary for allowbreak but not completely sure)?

Basically I want to know if there is something like `\abc` which can be introduced into something like `verylongword\abcmorewords` resulting in either `verylongwordmorewords` or `verylongword morewords`.

Comment: Post a MWE. `\allowbreak` works for my document.

Comment: It turns out that a space is required after an `\allowbreak`